# transpose datetime with label

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wish to transpose this datetime into a column with a label (name) associated with the times in range. Then ultimately add them to a sqlite table

I have searched and tried some of the suggestions here but I could nnot get what I'm looking for

2019-10-2   Bob
2019-10-3   Bob
2019-10-4   Bob

```
from datetime import date,datetime
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')


name = 'Bob'
startDate = pd.to_datetime(str('10/02/2019'))
endDate = pd.to_datetime(str('10/09/2019'))
d=pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate)

for i in d:
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':[i], 'Name':[name]})
df.transpose()
print(df)
```

I get only one date in a column with one name, not the range of dates between the startDate and endDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, don't use for-loop. Try this:

```
name = 'Bob'
startDate = pd.to_datetime(str('10/02/2019'))
endDate = pd.to_datetime(str('10/09/2019'))
d=pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate)

df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':d, 'Name':[name]*len(d)})

Out[918]:
        Date Name
0 2019-10-02  Bob
1 2019-10-03  Bob
2 2019-10-04  Bob
3 2019-10-05  Bob
4 2019-10-06  Bob
5 2019-10-07  Bob
6 2019-10-08  Bob
7 2019-10-09  Bob
```

On `transpose`(Note: `T` is alias for `tranpose()`)

```
df.T

Out[925]:
                        0                    1                    2  \
Date  2019-10-02 00:00:00  2019-10-03 00:00:00  2019-10-04 00:00:00
Name  Bob                  Bob                  Bob

                        3                    4                    5  \
Date  2019-10-05 00:00:00  2019-10-06 00:00:00  2019-10-07 00:00:00
Name  Bob                  Bob                  Bob

                        6                    7
Date  2019-10-08 00:00:00  2019-10-09 00:00:00
Name  Bob                  Bob
```